# Create a custom field in SharePoint that inherits from Taxonomy(Managed metadata) field

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

I need to make a custom taxonomy field in SharePoint and could use an example on how to do this. It should be something similar to this [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Field Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb861799(v%3Doffice.14))

Comment: Please show us what you already tried so far.

Comment: I have tried the example on the link above and it works, but apart from that I haven't been able to find anything about creating taxonomy custom fields in similar way...so if anyone has an example like that it would be great if he could post it